# solution for the following second order linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could anybody help me with the solution of:

$$a(1-x)^2x^2y''+(1-x)xy'+(x+b)y=0.$$
Consider $a>0$ and $b<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Similary to $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy=0$ for which we look for solutions on the form $x^k$ and similary to $a(1-x)^2y''+b(1-x)y'+cy=0$ for which we look for solutions on the form $(1-x)^h$, this draw us to try a particular solution on the form $x^k(1-x)^h$

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Let x= p/(1+p) and make the ansatz y(x)= 1/(1+p) u(p).